# Coupon code for Combo Pack in Magento Panel

Tags: magento

I have a Magento shopping cart in which i want to apply coupon code for amount of subtotal >=2000, now i have applied this from Magento panel and it is working..

But when i select two combo pack products the coupon code doesn't work..

E.g. If i select products (single) with amount of subtotal which is >=2000 Rupees it is working...

secondly if i select one product (combo) and another single products which gives subtotal amount >=2000 Rupees it is working too...

But if i select two products which are combo packs worth rupees 1000 and 1200 the coupon code doesn't work .

Please let me know how to set this for all products irrespective of type (combo or single) which is having worth rupees >=2000 from Magento Panel.

Please help me out..

Regards,
Krunal Panchal

Answer (score 0):

whatever rule which u have created -> Edit -> Action Tab -> leave your second portion as it is default[ Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items) ]